# Domain of convergence of $\sum n e^{-n}z^n$ .

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $\sum n e^{-n}z^n$ be a power series. To find the radius of convergence and domain of convergence of the power series....

I have found the radius of convergence to be $e$ by ratio test. Also seen that at $z=e$ the series diverges.

Can we conclude from here that the domain of convergence is the open ball $|z| < e$?

Comment: No, you must check $z=-e$ separately. Fortunately this is easy.

Comment: The Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula (Cauchy, in 1829, and Hadamard, independently, in 1889!): Let $1/R=\lim \sup_{n\to \infty} |A_n|^{1/n}.$... (where $1/0=\infty$ and $1/\infty =0.$ ). If $|z|<R$ then $\sum_nA_nz^n$ converges. If $|z|>R$ then $\sum_nA_nz^n$ diverges.

Comment: Convergence of  $\sum_n  A_nz^n$  when $|z|$ is equal to the radius of convergence is a complicated  Q in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've done so far... no, you haven't got enough to conclude that the domain of convergence is the open ball of radius $e$. The boundary behavior might be more subtle; consider, for example, a similar series like

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}$$

whose domain of convergence includes $z = -1$, although the radius is $1$.

---

However, in this particular case, you're ok. Note that if $|z| = e$ then

$$|n e^{-n} z^n| = n \left(\frac{|z|}{e}\right)^n = n \to \infty$$

and so the series diverges on the entire boundary.